# Get all fields when making a innerjoin queryset in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

im trying to obtain all the fields when making a inner join queryset like this one:

```
querysetd = MenuResponseModel.objects.select_related('option').filter(MenuID=menuCreateId)
```

But it keep responding me with the main table fields only.

> {'id': 2, 'option_id': 7, 'userName': 'miguel', 'MenuID_id': UUID('057e4185-c79d-40ff-b90d-0bee254754c8'), 'comments': 'sin cebolla por favor', 'date': datetime.date(2019, 3, 13)}

These are my models

```
class MenuResponseModel(models.Model):
    option = models.ForeignKey(Menu, blank=False)
    userName = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True )
    MenuID= models.ForeignKey(MenuCreateModel, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=200)         
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

class Menu(models.Model):
    option = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    MenuID= models.ForeignKey(MenuCreateModel, default=uuid.uuid4, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Thanks for the help-

Comment: How do you know it only returns the main object? How did you get the dictionary representation that you quoted?

Comment: i get a dict of all the values when execute this code
querysetd = MenuResponseModel.objects.select_related('option').filter(MenuID=menuCreateId).values('description').values()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values from your ForeignKey Field also exists in the Queryset. If you want to see those, you can use [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) method of the queryset:

```
querysetd.values('option__some_field', 'option__some_field2')  # and so on
```

Or directly access the value like this:

```
for i in querysetd:
   i.option.some_field  # will not hit database as you have used select related
```

Comment: Doesnt work, when i add values and the fields i get the followind error message

` Cannot resolve keyword 'description' into field. Choices are: MenuID, MenuID_id, comments, date, id, option, option_id, userName `

Comment: you need to use `__` when accessing the fields in ForignKey. So you should use like this `querysetd.values('option__description')`